# Simple CMS for designers

Tags: open-source, content-management-system

I realise that this question may get downvoted, but I'll try to outline my needs as clearly as possible.

Basically I've been looking at Perch, a very simple CMS that can be added in at the end of a website design. For me, its core benefits are its ease of use - simply adding a line of code for areas where content may change. It also has a very simple admin area.

I've looked at concrete5 and that doesn't seem to be as simple.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a simple CMS? I am fundamentally a Web designer, not developer, and am looking for something as quick to set up as Perch, but free.

By simple CMS I mean simple to install and easy for someone with no technical knowledge to understand on the admin side. Also simple in its implementation.

The sites are simple, with maybe a blogging functionality but other than that there is only a need to edit text and images.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention any specific site needs and that would be a factor in determining the best CMS solution. However, based on what you stated, I would suggest looking at Wordpress. It has a lot of functionality and can be extended to accommodate the needs of most websites. It is very simple to learn and there is a vast community of users/developers who can help get you up to speed with using Wordpress. In my opinion, Wordpress is the best choice for someone wanting/needing to learn CMS development. Later, you may want to move to Joomla or Drupal.

Comment: Yeah I've played with Wordpress, but I don't like the way I have to conform my site to its architecture and not vice versa.

Comment: Understandable... I found a reference to frog (http://www.madebyfrog.com). I have never used it, but you may want to look at it and see if it would meet your needs.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a free alternative to perch, I think you should look at [couchcms](http://www.couchcms.com/). It is quite similar to perch but is open source.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [AnchorCMS.com](http://anchorcms.com), its simple, dead easy to use and open source ([Anchor - Github](https://github.com/anchorcms/anchor-cms)).

Answer (score 0):

Define "simple"? Small code base? Easy to administer? Doesn't require a bunch of extensions?

My 3 standards are WordPress, Joomla, and Drupal, ordered by increasing complexity of the site's needs. I can have a very nice site put together in a few hours with any of them after some experience. There's no such thing as a CMS without a learning curve.